# Ternary operator used for populating different Lists - compiler error

Tags: java, generics, compiler-errors

When I try to use ternary operator for choosing which array list to add to it works:

```
List<String> a = new ArrayList<>();
List<String> b = new ArrayList<>();

(true ? a : b).add("test");
```

When I try to initiate the list in ternary operator:

```
List<String> a = new ArrayList<>();

(true ? a : new ArrayList<>()).add("test");
```

It does not work with the error:

> The method add(capture#1-of ? extends Object) in the type
>   List is not applicable for the
>   arguments (String)

I don't understand why this is not legal. Although pointless, the following works fine:

```
(new ArrayList<>()).add("test");
```

I want to better understand Java compiler and how it works and this is why I ask the question. I understand this is not very practical.

**Edit:**

The key thing that I would like to understand is why it does not work in ternary, but does work fine on its own.

Comment: The compiler tries to infer the type of the ternary from the types of its operands, and the operands' diamond operator content from the destination of the generic assignment. There isn't enough information in the expression to resolve both. Don't use the diamond operator; specify the generic element type.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's because the diamond notation (`new ArrayList<>`) uses type inference from your reference (`List<String>`).

See Oracle documentation [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/type-inference-generic-instance-creation.html).

However in your second case, the compiler cannot / is not designed to infer the generic type from the other term of the ternary condition (`a`'s reference).

You can fix it by using the following idiom, with an explicity generic parameter:

```
(true ? a : new ArrayList<String>()).add("test");
```

Comment: So why (new ArrayList<>()).add("test"); on its own works fine?

Comment: Because it is an equivalent of writing `new ArrayList<Object>().add("test")`;

Answer (score 4):

Specifying a type variable will solve your problem:

```
(true ? a : new ArrayList<String>()).add("test");
```

The problem is that compiler can not automatically detect what type variable to use in this case, that what error talks about actually.

More specifically, just `new ArrayList<>()` without direct assigning it to the type-parametrized variable, is an equivalent of writing `new ArrayList<Object>()`, i.e. it is interpreted as `Object` type variable.

Comment: Why does (new ArrayList<>()).add("test"); work fine?

Comment: Because it is an equivalent of writing `new ArrayList<Object>().add("test")`;

Comment: Yeah, but why is this not equivalent of writing that when used inside ternary?

Comment: See the answer of @Mena: `That's because the diamond notation (new ArrayList<>) uses type inference from your reference (List<String>).`